# TeX Gyre Termes on Linux Mint 19.3

Tags: fonts, luatex, context

I installed `context` and `pandoc` on clean Linux Mint 19.3. When I run `mtxrun --script font --list termes` I get:

```
identifier             familyname      fontname               filename   subfont   instances

texgyretermesregular   texgyretermes   texgyretermesregular   qtmr.afm
```

But then I want to use it like that:

```
\definefont[toc-h1][texgyretermesregular at 13pt]
\definefont[toc-h2][texgyretermesregular at 12.5pt]
```

I got error during export:

```
fonts           > defining > unknown font 'texgyretermesregular', loading aborted
fonts           > defining > unable to define 'texgyretermesregular' as 'toc-h2--0'
```

Can I solve it somehow? On other systems it works, for example Ubuntu or ArchLinux...

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly specify the type of lookup you want to perform.  Therefore prefix the name by `name:`.  You are also loading the font without any features, but most likely you want to enable the default features.  To this end add `*default`.

```
\definefont[toc-h1][name:texgyretermesregular*default at 13pt]
\definefont[toc-h2][name:texgyretermesregular*default at 12.5pt]
\starttext

{\getvalue{toc-h1} Foo}

{\getvalue{toc-h2} Bar}

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

Using filename instead of familyname solved the problem.